# Wrong URL redirection in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have used following redirection rule in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/index.html http://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]
```

Now when I open

```
http://www.example.com/patient_login/
```

It is redirecting me to

```
http://www.example.com/blog/
```

But it works fine with any other path. For example if I goto

```
http://www.example.com/practitioner_login/
```

It is working fine. Please help. I want to open the patient login URL

Comment: Sounds like you initially tried with that url when you had a different rule? Your browser probably cached that redirect.

Comment: Yes. It was cached by my browser. Now when I open this in incognito window, nothing is working. So I used my old redirection rule which is RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com/blog/ [R=301,L]

Please suggest me how to do it. I just want to redirect my index.html to /blog and leave the rest as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue would seem to have been caused by the browser cache, as Kevin pointed out in comments.

> I just want to redirect my index.html to /blog and leave the rest as it is

The directive you posted above would never work in a `.htaccess` file because of the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.html /blog/ [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) to `301` (permanent) redirect when you are sure it's working OK - to avoid any caching problems (again).

Comment: Thanks. I also tried another hack. As I've to redirect only my index.html page so I changed this page to index.php and wrote redirection there using header() function of php which allows us to do redirection.